# Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried: #56

Tags: linux, node.js

I am getting the following error when I'm starting `GenieACS cwmp`. I have also tried to rebuild several times.

```
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
→ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/build/xmljs.node
→ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/build/Debug/xmljs.node
→ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/build/Release/xmljs.node
→ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/out/Debug/xmljs.node
→ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/Debug/xmljs.node
→ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/out/Release/xmljs.node
→ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/Release/xmljs.node
→ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/build/default/xmljs.node
→ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/compiled/0.10.25/linux/x64/xmljs.node
at bindings (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88:9)
at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/lib/bindings.js:1:99)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/genieacs/node_modules/libxmljs/index.js:4:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
18 Dec 18:34:26 - Worker 7837 died (8)
```

Answer (score 21):

I spoke to the developer, and he said that it was a bug in node-gyp, you should simply do the following:

```
npm install node-gyp
```

if that didn't solve the issue, then you can install libxmljs again just to be sure

```
npm install libxmljs
```

i just tried it, worked like a charm

Comment: Usually, node-gym should be installed with -g parameter, globally.

Comment: In my case it was complaining about the bindings for [ursa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ursa) package. Fixed by simply installing it with `npm install ursa`.

Answer (score 8):

I did all the actions from this thread and many others but without success.
then I just removed my 'node_modules' folder and run "npm install" again, and it solved the issue. So you can also try this ;)

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue before

I downgraded the dependency of libxmljs to @0.11.0 (package.json) and ran `sudo npm install libxmljs`

Comment: It's easier to simply use `npm install libxml@0.11.0` instead of editing package file.

Comment: @erm3nda `npm install libxmljs@0.11.0`

Answer (score 4):

`npm rebuild` may resolve the problem

Comment: this one first one i did among all solutions, and it works XD

Answer (score 1):

I just went around the houses to resolve this issue.

I was using PM2 and had multiple node apps running on the one server, I'm not sure why, but when I killed all the apps and then did an 'npm i' in the troublesome project, it all went through fine. 
No sudo, no deleting node_modules and all running the latest version of node.

Hope this helps

Comment: I deleted the old app that was running on pm2 then started it again , it worked like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**(for me)**:**

Deleting my **yarn.lock** file then running <**yarn**> in the terminal is what finally worked. At some point the project I'm working on had both *npm* & *yarn* package managers utilized and would fail every time I tried to run <**npm install**>.

**Environment:**

- macOS - Catalina - *10.15.2*
- Node-Expat Version - *"node-expat": "^2.3.17"*
- Sharp Version - *"sharp": "^0.23.4",*
- Node Version(on local machine) - *12.12.0.*

**Previous Attempts**(did not resolve)**:**

1. Removed *node_modules* and ran *npm install*.
2. Ran *node-gyp install*.
3. Ran *npm install -g node-gyp*.
4. ran *node-gyp rebuild -g*.
5. Removed the *sharp* directory from the *node_modules* and ran *#4* above.
6. Removed *node-expat* and ran *npm install node-expat*.

**Notes and Credit:**

It was a colleague of mine that finally figured this out after my attempts failed. However, I went to work on another project the next day and experienced the same error when performing an *npm i*. Without hesitation I skipped all the attempts I had tried in the other project, deleted my yarn.lock file, ran yarn and was back in business.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with the leveldown NPM, tried the above answer and didn't work.
Finally downgraded node from v11 to v8.15 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This happens when `npm install` command fails installing some of the packages and continues to install other package, due to bad network connectivity or network disconnections during `npm install`.

Solution 1: Deleting `node_modules` and `package_lock.json` file and run `npm install` command again.

Solution 2: Just run `npm rebuild`, this command will just complete the installation of incomplete packages.