# Meteor run server getting error: "Could not locate the bindings file. [...]bcrypt[...]"

Tags: node.js, meteor, docker, dockerfile, bcrypt

## Problem

I try to run a Meteor server application in a Docker image. Running the main file to start the server results in an error, see details below:
`Could not locate the bindings file.` (My system: Macbook Pro, OSX 10.11.4)

## Question

Has anybody an idea how to solve this error?

## Unsuccessful attempts to solve the problem

1. Running `npm rebuild` as proposed [here](https://github.com/pilwon/ultimate-seed/issues/54) didn't work
2. Proposal by [Nick Bull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2483271/nick-bull): Running `npm install --unsafe-perm node-gyp` and  `npm install --unsafe-perm  libxmljs` didn't work. Both executed in the docker container in `/home/build/bundle/programs/server`. (The `--unsafe-perm` flag is [needed](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-iojs/issues/72) due to root rights in docker image)

## Details

1. The `Dockerfile` (inspired by [meteorhacks/meteord](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteord))

```
FROM debian:wheezy

ENV sourcedir /home/source
ENV builddir /home/build
RUN mkdir ${sourcedir} && mkdir ${builddir}

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y curl bzip2 build-essential python git

RUN \
    NODE_VERSION=4.4.7 \
    && NODE_ARCH=x64 \
    && NODE_DIST=node-v${NODE_VERSION}-linux-${NODE_ARCH} \
    && cd /tmp \
    && curl -O -L http://nodejs.org/dist/v${NODE_VERSION}/${NODE_DIST}.tar.gz \
    && tar xvzf ${NODE_DIST}.tar.gz \
    && rm -rf /opt/nodejs \
    && mv ${NODE_DIST} /opt/nodejs \
    && ln -sf /opt/nodejs/bin/node /usr/bin/node \
    && ln -sf /opt/nodejs/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

RUN curl -sL https://install.meteor.com | sed s/--progress-bar/-sL/g | /bin/sh

ADD . ${sourcedir}
RUN cd ${sourcedir} \
    && meteor build  --directory ${builddir} --server=http://localhost:3000

RUN cd ${builddir}/bundle/programs/server/ && npm install
```

2. The Error message, when running `node main.js` in the `bundle` folder:

```
/home/build/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                        throw(ex);
                        ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Debug/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/out/Debug/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/Debug/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/out/Release/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/Release/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/default/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/compiled/4.4.7/linux/x64/bcrypt_lib.node
    at bindings (/home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Module.Mp.load (/home/build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/reify/node/runtime.js:16:23)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.Npm.require (/home/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:190:18)
```

Comment: which version of Meteor are you using? The recently-released version 1.4 supports node 4.4.7.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Idg! When the Dockerfile is build it downloads the latest version, here: Meteor 1.4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the bug: 
The problem was the definition of the envrionment varibale `buildir` in the `Dockerfile`:
`ENV builddir /home/build`
The build process for `bcrypt` seems to use the same variable, and builds the files `bcrypt_lib.node` and `obj.target` in that directory. So they were missing in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

According to many [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541586/error-could-not-locate-the-bindings-file-tried-56) [sources](https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/issues/253), it's a bug in node-gyp. Try this:

```
npm install node-gyp
npm install libxmljs
```

and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Nick Bull! I still get the error when the two packages are installed in `programs/server`. For running in the docker container with root rights the `npm install --unsafe-perm` flag was required ([source](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-iojs/issues/72)).

Answer (score 0):

If you're in censored country like Kazakhstan then running meteor through vpn the first time will help, since it fails at downloading gyp plugins. There should be a line somewhere about download failing, not when you run meteor start specifically.