# node.js in docker - Could not locate the bindings file .../bcrypt_lib.node

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a custom node.js app that runs fine in a VM, but when I try to run it in docker, I get an error

```
Error initializing middleware
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Debug/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/out/Debug/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/Debug/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/out/Release/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/Release/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/default/bcrypt_lib.node
 → /usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/compiled/4.8.4/linux/x64/bcrypt_lib.node
    at bindings (/usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/co-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
```

Dockerfile looks like below

```
FROM node:4-onbuild

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
ENV PORT 8080

RUN npm install
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm node-gyp
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm libxmljs
RUN npm rebuild

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I've already added the suggestions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808841/meteor-run-server-getting-error-could-not-locate-the-bindings-file-bcryp) without success (installing node-gyp and libxmljs, doing npm rebuild). I am using `"bcryptjs": "^2.3.0"`.

Any suggestions how to make it work are appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/pilwon/ultimate-seed/issues/54

Comment: Thank you, yes. I've did the rebuild already and use bcryptjs. But thanks to you I've went through the whole project again and found the root cause :) co-bcrypt was there in package.json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of the problem was using `co-bcrypt`. After removing it from the `package.json` and replacing all the require statements with `bcryptjs`, the error is gone.