# react-native: Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:

Tags: react-native, npm

I am getting the below error when I try to execute npm start after installing the react native dependencies. Can you please guide me on how to fix this issue.

/home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:135
throw err;
^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/build/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/build/Debug/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/out/Debug/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/Debug/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/out/Release/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/Release/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/build/default/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/compiled/10.13.0/linux/x64/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/addon-build/release/install-root/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/addon-build/debug/install-root/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/addon-build/default/install-root/node_expat.node
→ /home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-x64/node_expat.node
at bindings (/home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:126:9)
at Object. (/home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/node-expat/lib/node-expat.js:4:32)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object. (/home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/xml2json/lib/xml2json.js:1:13)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object. (/home/rakesh95/Desktop/Rakesh/MyFamilyPlan/node_modules/xml2json/lib/index.js:3:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

Try to first:

`npm install node-gyp`

if that didn't solve the issue, then you can install libxmljs again just to be sure

`npm install libxmljs`

Got it from "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541586/error-could-not-locate-the-bindings-file-tried-56"